# How to deploy smart contract using Remix 0.8.0 and MetaMask?

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, metamask

How do I deploy a contract on a test network using `Remix 0.8.0` and `MetaMask` on a `Firefox` or `Chrome` browser?

Answer (score 0):

This recipe supposes that user has installed `MetaMask` and `Remix`

---

1. Open `Metamask` and type password (indicates last session closed properly);
2. Select a `Test Network`, `localhost:8545` or `Custom RPC` (don't do this on Main Network, unless your contract is perfect and ready to be launched);
3. Select an account with some (dummy) `Ether`;
4. Open `Remix` (I'm using `version 0.8.0`);
5. Click `Deploy` icon, left ribbon;
6. Modify `Environment` from `JavaScript VM` to `Injected Web3` (use `Metamask`);
7. Deploy contract.

---

IF YOU ARE RUNNING YOUR OWN TEST NETWORK:

1. Ensure that some mining is going on in your test network;
2. Ensure that enough peers are connected to reach consensus.

---

IF YOU RUN INTO DEPLOYMENT ISSUES WITH RPC
(`Internal JSON-RPC error` with an otherwise operational RPC server, for example)

1. Close every open tab on every window in current browser;
2. Restart browser;
3. Close any tabs which open up;
4. Restart browser (skip if no tabs open in `step 3`;
5. Follow `STEP 1` thru `STEP 7` at the beginning of this answer.